# How to deal with lines starting with '=' in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I want to obtain a simple CSV file that looks like this:

```
Filename,Value1,Value2
filename1.ext,0.38,0.44
filename2.ext,0.60,0.50
...
```

However, -unfortunately- some of my filenames start with `=` and that messes up the content in Excel, so those lines (well, cells) are replaced with `#NAME?`. So how can I prevent Excel to modify any of the content while saving as .csv?

**P.S.:** I'm actually obtaining the *.csv files programmatically, but then I need to replace some columns across files, so I -kind of- need to use Excel.

### Edit

I tried the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438589/bypass-excel-csv-formula-conversion-on-fields-starting-with-or), but in that case Excel actually removes the = sign in the beginning, hence modifying the content.. It seems like I'm going to quit doing this but I still wonder if there is a solution for this.
Thanks,

Comment: csv files are plain text files. You don't need to use excel to manipulate them - most scripting languages will do the job ...

Comment: Well yeah, I was trying to save time but I guess it would be faster to program it :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the cells as text so it wont interpret the = sign.

You can use `'` to escape the = sign.

Or, as you already obtain your *.csv programmatically, you could script it with a scripting language of your choice. CSV are just plain text files that are associated with MS Excel by default.

Answer (score 0):

The best and most general solution is to encapsulate all texts in the CSV with " (double quotes). That works in Excel, and most other tools with understand that too.