# In Excel, how to treat values starting with = as text and not a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have data exported from a database that's in a CSV that I need to view and manipulate in Excel. The problem is that some of the values in the cells start with an equal sign ( = ) so Excel thinks this is a formula and will try to interpret it, which fails and I'm left with "#NAME?" as the value when I save the file again. I need to preserve the data exactly as it was, so I can't escape or encapsulate it as recommended here: [How to deal with lines starting with '=' in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1098435/how-to-deal-with-lines-starting-with-in-excel)

Is there any way to completely turn off formulas in Excel so that values starting with = are ignored? etc.

I know that one option is to use a text editor to convert the = into some other character which doesn't occur anywhere else in the data and then after re-exporting from Excel use the text editor again to convert all instances of that character back into = but I'm hoping to avoid that if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: you can set the column in which they are put to Text.

Comment: Can you not escape it using `'` at the start of the line?

Comment: @spikey_richie I can, but when I export the data as a CSV the ' is there and as ' appear elsewhere in the data I'm not sure how to remove them after.

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried to do that using the following steps:
Click on the column heading to select entire column.
Click Format > Cells.
Click the Number tab.
Select “Text” from the Category list.
Click OK.

But it did not work, I still have #NAME? in those cells (when click the cell I see the value in the entry field, but it's #NAME? when saved as CSV)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula below might help depending on how wide spread the issue is.

[image]

Comment: This worked in my case. Thank you!